# Mercurial, abort: authorization failed

Tags: iis, mercurial, https, repository, authorization

I'm having problems accessing a mercurial repository. (mercurial 1.7.1)

Its set up on IIS6 windows 2003 over Https,

I can access the site through a browser using the same credentials,

I can access the site if I enable anonymous access for the virtual directory in IIS, but I need to use the Integrated Windows authentication.

I have tried setting the path in my hgrc file to:

```
[paths]
default = https://username:password@example.site.com/hg/hgweb.cgi/TestRepository
```

then if I try to Push or Pull I get the error message:

abort: authorization failed

Any Ideas?

Comment: It's not an answer, and probably not even related, but I've had authentication issues when trying to reach our hg repo via hg in a virtualbox linux, while no trouble at all from native Windows hg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the Directory security authentication mode to basic authentication. For the time being this seem to be sufficient for our needs

Answer (score 1):

The most useful output is probably in your webserver/IIS logs -- check there.  You can also try `--debug` on the mercurial command line to get a little more output, but it's likely going to be on the web server side.

Comment: thanks for you suggestion Ry4an, I had a look at the webserver/IIS log and it is writing pairs=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000000000000000000000000000000000&cmd=between 443 ...mercurial/proto-1.0   which doesn't mean much to me, have solved this by changing the directory permissions for now.